# Initialization of object variable in c#?

Tags: c#

A static variable is a variable that is just one copy for all the class objects and can be accessed even there is no object of class.

But I want a variable separate for each object and want to initialize it in a constructor.

Comment: show us the code you have so far, I guess you are talking about static variable.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: As in the comments below, what you're looking for is a `readonly` variable:

```
class MyClass {
    readonly int myInteger;

    public MyClass() {
        myInteger = 10; // works
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        myInteger = 5; // not allowed
    }
}
```

<del>It sounds like you're talking about a `static` variable, not a `constant`. Just do like this:</del>

```
class MyClass {
    static int myInteger;

    public void DoSomething() {
        myInteger = 5; // is now changed for all instances
    }
}
```

Comment: static variable is a variable that is just one copy for all the class objects and can be accessed even there is no object of class. but i want a variable separate for each object and it should be constant and want to initialize it in a constructor. .

Comment: Ah, I see! I've updated my answer :) You want `readonly`.

Comment: you are right . . . readonly is working well as i required.